# can you recover moved site in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Hi I have moved a site instead of copying and made a lot of edit on the moved location. I was just wondering is there any way to recover the files in the original form.

Answer (score 0):

Having versioning activated would allow you to recover historic versions of your files. Another option could be to contact Microsoft. Given this [link](https://itsolutionsblog.net/the-backup-options-in-sharepoint-online/) you should be able to get a backup from them.

> 3. Make a service request in your portal.
>
> This option is somewhat bothersome, but might sometimes be necessary. If you really screw something up in you Site collection and you are not able to access it anymore is this the way to go!
>   Microsoft will make a backup every 12 hours and keep it for 14 days. Currently the only restore option is  a Full site collection restore to the same URL. I personally hope that they are going to extend this functionality, so that we might restore to a different URL or even download these backups offline.

Besides that I don't see a solution for you.

Comment: but if it is full site collection restore from the backup i will loose what i have done after ?

Comment: Not if you make a backup or copy of what you've done now.

Answer (score 0):

I think best option is make a copy of you current site (where u made all edits) , now u have 2 copies of same site.

Now contact MSFT support and restore the site collection from backup.